# Update historical commit message in SourceTree

Tags: git, sourcetree

I have several commits in my history that I would like to update the wording on. I have not pushed these changes to my remote repo.

I have only been able to find a way to reset the *last* commit message. Is there a way to do it for other commits than the most recent?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `rebase` feature to achieve your goal of rewording commit messages for one or more commits in the history.

The application [SourceTree is able to perform an interactive rebase](https://www.atlassian.com/blog/sourcetree/interactive-rebase-sourcetree). In SourceTree's interactive rebase screen, you can simply double-click on the message column in order to change one or more commit messages.

On the command line, this is most easily done using `git rebase -i <commit-id>`.  (Actually, you can do much more interesting stuff with Git's [rebase command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase).) Just do the rebase with a `<commit id>` that is older than the one in question and replace the command `pick` with `reword` (and the old message with the new message) for all those commits the commit message of which you want to update.